# Задача на питоне : "Покраска кубиков"

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм

Проблема в том, что при вводе чисел `11 4` и `1 1 2 1 2 2 1 4 4 2 4`

Выводится результат: `22`, а должно `21`!

**Условие задачи**

На ленте в один ряд расставлено `n` кубиков. Каждый кубик необходимо покрасить в определенный цвет. Все цвета пронумерованы числами от `1` до `k`. Покраска выполняется роботом, который может перемещаться от одного кубика к другому, и красить один выбранный кубик в определенный цвет. Конструктивно робот устроен так, что он может сначала красить кубики в цвет номер `1`, затем в цвет номер `2` и так далее в порядке возрастания. Вернутся к цвету с меньшим номером после того, как был выбран цвет с большим номером, нельзя.

Среди всего прочего робот тратит время на перемещение между кубиками. Будем считать, что перемещение между двумя соседними кубиками занимает ровно `одну секунду`. Требуется составить последовательность действий для робота, в которой время, затраченное на перемещение между кубиками, будет минимально возможным.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Рассмотрим пример на схеме. Имеется `11` кубиков, которые надо покрасить в 3 цвета с номерами `1`, `2` и `4`.

Движение робота из схемы будет таковым: начнет красить цветом номер `1` с `1` кубика, далее `2`, `4` и `7` кубик. Это займет у него `6 секунд`. После робот поменяет цвет на номер `2` и пойдет красить кубик `6`, потом `5` и `3`, развернется и пойдет красить `10`. Это займет у него `11 секунд`. Далее робот сменит цвет на `4`, т.к. нет кубиков, которые нужно покрасить в `3`, и пойдет красить `11` кубик, после `9` и `8`. Это займет у него `4 секунды`. В результате робот затратит на перемещение `21 секунду`.

Обратите внимание, что по условию задачи робот может выбрать цвет 4 только после цвета 2. Существуют другие возможные маршруты движения робота, но они займут больше времени.

Напишите программу, которая найдет минимально возможное суммарное время перемещения робота между кубиками до момента пока все они не будут покрашены. Изначально робот находится у кубика номер `1`.

**Формат входных данных**.

На вход в первой строке подается два натуральных числа `n` и `k` — количество кубиков и количество цветов, `1≤n`, `k≤100000` Во второй строке на вход подается `n` натуральных чисел `1,2,…,c1,c2,…,cn`, где `ci` — требуемый цвет `i`-того кубика, `1≤ci≤k`.

**Формат выходных данных**

Выведите одно число — минимально возможное время перемещения между кубиками.

А вот мой код:

```py
def min_robot_movement(n, k, colors):
    positions = [[] for _ in range(k)]
    current_position = 1
    total_time = 0

    for i in range(len(colors)):
        positions[colors[i] - 1].append(i + 1)

    for color_positions in positions:
        color_positions.sort()
        for position in color_positions:
            total_time += abs(current_position - position)
            current_position = position

    return total_time

# Пример использования
n, k = map(int, input().split())
colors = list(map(int, input().split()))

result = min_robot_movement(n, k, colors)
print("Минимальное время перемещения робота:", result)
```

Comment: @ПавелЕриковstandwithRussia надеюсь вам стало понятнее

Comment: Что-то я не вижу в вашем решении прохода по кубикам одного цвета в одну сторону, а потом в другую. Только в одну сторону проход вижу я. И вы просто последовательно берёте кубики, а в алгоритме то совсем другое, тут указатель туда-сюда бегает, а не просто через `range` кубики перебираются. Я пока не понимаю, как выбрать оптимальное направление куда лучше сначала пойти, а куда потом, но вы хотя бы хождение туда-сюда хоть начиная с любого направления сделайте, а дальше будет проще уже. Пока у вас вообще не похоже происходящее на описание. Вы ищете ближайший кубик такого же цвета, а дальше то что.

Comment: @CrazyElf ну я пробую решать, но не получается

Comment: Для начала попробуйте просто ходить туда-сюда слева направо. Т.е. сначала идёте с текущего кубика на минимальный индекс кубика нужного цвета, потом на максимальный. Переходите на следующий цвет и т.д. Это для начала. А потом придётся подумать - может не всегда будет оптимально так ходить, а когда-то будет оптимальнее ходить вправо, а потом влево. Но сначала сделайте хоть простой вариант всегда лево-право. Намётки у вас есть, нужно довести их до ума.

Comment: @CrazyElf, нужно динамическое программирования для поиска направлений (с кешем на два (!) значения). Жадным алгоримом обойтись, видимо, не получится.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Ну и хорошо, но пусть напишет для начала заготовку с хоть каким-то хождением туда-сюда, пока это вообще не то. Переписать дальше на поиск направлений будет уже проще.

Comment: Жили-были баран да овца, скосили они стожок сенца. Не рассказать ли сказку с конца?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ваша ошибка в том что все цвета обрабатываются слева на право. Например `2 2 1` робот будет красить так: пойдёт направо до конца, вернётся налево до конца, закрасит двойки. Всего пять шагов, а достаточно четырёх.

Заметим что из группы кубиков одного цвета достаточно оставить только самый левый и самый правый кубики. Кубики между ними на время перемещения не влияют. Если робот в позиции *p*, то он может красить группу двумя способами: *p -> левый кубик -> правый кубик* и *p -> правый кубик -> левый кубик*. Соответственно после покраски группы робот окажется на одном из концов группы. Для каждого из концов будем помнить минимальное число шагов до этой позиции. В конце из двух позиций выберем минимальное расстояние.

Сложность *O(n + k)*.

```
n, k = map(int, input().split())

ranges = [[n + 1, 0] for _ in range(k)]
for i, c in enumerate(map(int, input().split()), start=1):
    r = ranges[c - 1]
    r[0] = min(i, r[0])
    r[1] = max(i, r[1])

ends = (0, 1), (0, 1)
for lo, hi in ranges:
    if lo <= hi:
        ends = (
            (min(d + abs(p - hi) + (hi - lo) for d, p in ends), lo),
            (min(d + abs(p - lo) + (hi - lo) for d, p in ends), hi)
        )
print(min(d for d, _ in ends))
```

Comment: Видна рука мастера...

Comment: `r[1] = max(i, r[1])` --> `r[1] = i`

Comment: @rotabor, это да. А для минимума можно делать присвоение только первый раз. Но я хотел подчеркнуть симметрию в  обработке данных.

Comment: Для минимума, как ни крути, одну проверку делать нужно.

Comment: Я не захотел использовать упорядочивание вместо сортировки, потому что на `k` никаких ограничений не наложено, что не совсем корректно, конечно. ПОсмотрим, пролезет ли сортировка.

Comment: В секции "формат входных данных" есть ограничение на *k*.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы закрасить кубики одного цвета, нужно от самого левого дойти до самого правого (или наоборот, перемещение тоже). Играет роль, с какой стороны подойти к следующему цвету. Начинаем искать кратчайший путь с конца, так как *путь по оставшимся цветам не зависит от расположения предыдущих цветов*: что меньше, подойти к левому кубику следующего цвета (тогда дальше пойдём с правого), или к правому кубику (тогда дальше пойдём с левого). Поскольку с последнего кубика нам перемещаться никуда не нужно, то к последнему цвету можно подойти с любой стороны.

```
n, k = map(int, input().split())
ci = sorted(zip(map(int, input().split()), range(n)), key = lambda c: c[0]) # сопоставляем каждому кубику номер, а потом сортируем по цветам
cc = [(0, 0)]
cR = cL = ci[0]
for i in range(1, n):
    if ci[i][0] != cL[0]:
        cc.append((cL[1], cR[1]))
        cL = ci[i]
    cR = ci[i]
cc.append((cL[1], cR[1])) # получили список левого и правого кубиков для каждого цвета
sl = sr = 0
for i in range(len(cc) - 1, 0, -1):
    r = cc[i][1] - cc[i][0]
    nl = min(abs(cc[i][0] - cc[i - 1][1]) + sl, abs(cc[i][1] - cc[i - 1][1]) + sr)
    nr = min(abs(cc[i][0] - cc[i - 1][0]) + sl, abs(cc[i][1] - cc[i - 1][0]) + sr)
    sl, sr = nl + r, nr + r
print(min(sl, sr))
```

Сложность тут "сортировка массива n" + "проход по массиву n" + "проход по массиву l (l<=k)".

Comment: Убрал свои замечания.

Comment: Итак, строгое доказательство (по рисунку в вопросе). Про закраску одним цветом уже написали. Очевидно, что есть минимальный путь с любой позиции. Рассматривая первый цвет, примем, что с позиции 3 минимальный путь п1, с позиции 10 - п2. Тогда от первого цвета из позиции 1 мы можем пойти по пути 1-7-3 или 1-7-10. Соответственно пути будут 6+4+п1 и 6+3+п2 – выберем из них минимальный. Из позиции 7 мы можем пойти по пути 7-1-3 или 7-1-10. Соответственно пути будут 6+2+п1 и 6+9+п2 – выберем из них минимальный. Таким образом мы получили минимальные пути для позиций 1 и 7. -->

Comment: --> Если бы начали не с первого цвета, то смогли бы перейти к предыдущему, а так идём к позиции 1.

Comment: Собственно, в этой задаче ни пройденный путь не зависит от осташегося, ни наоборот. Поэтому можно начинать считать и с конца, и с начала.